# How to reference .net 4 class library from .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am using VS 2015 Update 3.
I added reference in my .net core project but I can't access to methods/members/classes. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you tried like this- `#if NET40        Service4.Test.PrintHi();      #endif`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sanket it is working now

Answer (score 2):

Since you have added Service4 class library reference only in .NET 4.0 dependencies section (refer below snapshot), You need to use Conditional Compilation.

[image: NET40 dependencies]

To access, Service4 members, you need to do like this-

```
#if NET40 
    Service4.Test.PrintHi(); 
#endif
```

These are list of preprocessor symbols used in #if directives:

> .NET Framework 2.0   --> NET20
>
> .NET Framework 3.5   --> NET35
>
> .NET Framework 4.0   --> NET40
>
> .NET Framework 4.5   --> NET45
>
> .NET Framework 4.5.1 --> NET451
>
> .NET Framework 4.5.2 --> NET452
>
> .NET Framework 4.6   --> NET46
>
> .NET Framework 4.6.1 --> NET461
>
> .NET Framework 4.6.2 --> NET462
>
> .NET Standard 1.0    --> NETSTANDARD1_0
>
> .NET Standard 1.1    --> NETSTANDARD1_1
>
> .NET Standard 1.2    --> NETSTANDARD1_2
>
> .NET Standard 1.3    --> NETSTANDARD1_3
>
> .NET Standard 1.4    --> NETSTANDARD1_4
>
> .NET Standard 1.5    --> NETSTANDARD1_5
>
> .NET Standard 1.6    --> NETSTANDARD1_6

For more details, refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-multitarget)